# Simplest way to change colour of select windows html

Tags: html, css

When the user of my site clicks on a select box, the colour of the window with the select options matches the body's colour, but I want to change this colour. For instance this code in CSS only affects the input box and not the smaller "window" that shows the options in the dropdown:

```
select {
background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

Is there a quick workaround for this or do I have to customize with jquery or some other UI.

Comment: Could you submit a screen shot describes what you really mean?

Comment: If you mean the arrow of the drop down list, It is impossible to change it using css. It is browser's and OS related feature.

Comment: `<select>` is notoriously unfriendly to CSS modifications and if your goal is to change how the selection dropdown or arrow look ( or in many cases the size of the box ) you'll have to rely on a JS solution that replaces `<select>` entirely.

Comment: @sємsєм I literally mean the window that pops up with the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<select>` is notoriously unfriendly to CSS modifications and if your goal is to change how the selection dropdown or arrow look ( or in many cases the size of the box ) you'll have to rely on a JS solution that replaces `<select>` entirely.

Some alternatives:

https://select2.github.io (jQuery solution)

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ (Bootstrap solution)

Answer (score 3):

You can style the `background-color` of a "`select` tag window" if you apply it to the `option` elements:

```css
select option {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Obviously this solution is unfotunately not working in all browsers...

Comment: this code doesn't seem to change the color to aliceblue, but rather it is still the default of blue in Chrome

Comment: It does... its just a very light blue... i've changed it to a darker blue

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to change the background colour of an `<option>` element. Here is some example code that does that:

HTML:

```
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="">First</option>
  <option value="">Second</option>
  <option value="">Third</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select, option {
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4h99eznb/

Comment: My understanding (and admittedly, the language is unclear) is that the user wants to color the actual dropdown menu, which is something CSS cannot directly control.

Comment: This examples does the dropdown menu colour fine @RobertC

Comment: In Safari and Chrome the red is only applied to the `<select>`.  The individual options (the dropdown menu: First / Second / Third) remain unaffected.

Comment: @RobertC So basically it is not possible or is there a workaround?

Comment: @RobertC I'm on Chrome v52 and it shows up correctly. Please see the jsFiddle.

Comment: Chrome is coloring `<select>` which is good and right and behaving correctly.  The OP wants the menu (First / Second / Third) to also be colored, which is something CSS cannot offer.